# Naming Objects in Mongo Array?

Tags: php, mongodb

Using PHP and Mongo I would like to update the users availability but cannot figure it out. How can I structure my collection to be able to reference availability groups.steve.availability?

Below is the structure of my "groups" collection:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "524327d536b82c7c5c842f6d"
},
"group_id": "testing",
"password": "test",
"users": [
    {
        "username": "steve",
        "availability": "null"
    },
    {
        "username": "joeb",
        "availability": "null"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reference it the way you've suggested: `groups.steve.availability`, you'd need to structure your documents more like below. (I'm not sure where `groups` is coming from).

This example would give you `users.steve.availability` by moving the user's name to a sub-field of the `users` field (`users.steve`).

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "524327d536b82c7c5c842f6d"
},
"group_id": "testing",
"password": "test",
"users": {
    "steve": {
        "availability": "null"
    },
    "joeb" : {
        "availability": "null"
    }
}
}
```

Or, you could just create fields directly on the document:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "524327d536b82c7c5c842f6d"
},
"group_id": "testing",
"password": "test",
"steve": {
        "availability": "null"
},
"joeb" : {
        "availability": "null"
}
}
```

That would allow you to just use `steve.availability.`

If you're trying to do a query though, you'd be better off leaving it more like you had it originally:

```
"users": [
{
    "username": "steve",
    "availability": "null"
}]
```

So, you could write queries that were like:

```
db.groups.find({"users.username" : "steve" })
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I am looking to query and update the availability of each user. Is it possible to query and update availability to yes, where group_id=testing and username=steve?

Is it possible to do that either way? If so, which way do you recommend?

Comment: Probably storing them as an array would be best -- but it's hard to know without understanding a lot more about your requirements.